# Batch file to loop through contents of a text file, create variables and move files with partial names

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have an area of folders which have hundreds of documents in each, a structure like below:

```
C:\myLibrary\Accident Investigation Report
C:\myLibrary\Address Change
C:\myLibrary\Medical Certificate
C:\myLibrary\New Starter
```

The documents within these folders are named like the below example (which are based on date stamp, time stamp, dept number, report type, employee name).

```
2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.xml
2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.pdf

2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.xml
2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.pdf
```

etc

(each are in their own obvious titled folder)

To identify which dept number the files come from (important bit) is the numbers after the date stamp & time stamp - which in the examples above are 165 & 147 respectively.

I'd like to move all of the files to another set folder structure (that's already been created) based on their dept numbers (each dept has another similar structure shown below);

```
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Accident Investigation Report
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Address Change
```

etc

So, as in the example files above after the batch file has run I should end up with;

```
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.pdf
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.xml
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Address Change\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Address Change - J Bloggs.pdf
C:\Dept Structure\165man\Address Change\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Address Change - J Bloggs.xml

C:\Dept Structure\147man\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Accident Investigation Report - L Test.pdf
C:\Dept Structure\147man\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Accident Investigation Report - L Test.xml
C:\Dept Structure\147man\Address Change\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.pdf
C:\Dept Structure\147man\Address Change\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.xml
```

I have a text file with all the dept managers numbers within, e.g.

```
003man
004man
005man
006man
007man
008man
009man
etc
etc
410man
```

From this I want to loop through the text file, create a variable based on the first 3 digits, add 'Accident' or to the end of this variable, check through the first 'C:\myLibrary\Accident Investigation Report' folder, find any file with that variable within the title and move it to the 'dept structure' directory named as above - phew!!

I've managed to find some script that 'nearly' accomplishes this which looks very simple;

```
`cd /D "C:\Test"`

`for /F %%i in (C:\Dept.txt) do set str1=%%i`

`set _dept=%str1%`
`set _dept=%_dept:~0,3%`
`set "str2=%_dept%`

`move "????????????????????%str2%*.*" "C:\Dept Structure\%str1%\Accident Investigation Report"`
```

It does actually move some of the files to the correct locations, however, this seems to run through the whole text file and only deal with the last line! So all the other lines are left alone and remaining files aren't moved.

Comment: you missed the amount you will pay for the script writer.

Comment: Do you have to filter out any of the department numbers?

Comment: foxidrive - Not particularly, it's just a case of going through the list of departments and checking to see if any files exist, if so then move them to their specific directory in the dept structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this - the top portion creates the test files and folders.  It then moves the files as you seem to want them moved.

```
@echo off
md "c:\mylibrary2\Accident Investigation Report\" 2>nul
md "c:\mylibrary2\Address Change\" 2>nul
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.pdf"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Accident Investigation Report - J Bloggs.xml"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Address Change\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Address Change - J Bloggs.pdf"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Address Change\2013-06-06 16-28-59 165 Address Change - J Bloggs.xml"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Accident Investigation Report - L Test.pdf"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Accident Investigation Report\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Accident Investigation Report - L Test.xml"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Address Change\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.pdf"
type nul > "c:\mylibrary2\Address Change\2013-06-11 15-38-07 147 Address Change - L Test.xml"



for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir "c:\mylibrary2" /a-d /b /s') do (
for /f "tokens=3" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
for /f "delims=" %%c in ("%%~dpa\.") do (
md "C:\Dept Structure2\%%bman\%%~nxc\" 2>nul
move "%%a" "C:\Dept Structure2\%%bman\%%~nxc\" >nul
)
)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Excuse me. I don't understand what the dept managers numbers file is used for. It is a waste of time to process all lines in this list if there are not files for all of they. This file would be useful if there are files that are NOT in this list and you want to omit they, but you had mentioned nothing about this point.

There are several ways to solve this problem. The Batch file below assume that there are not errors in all the names you have explained in your question.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all folders in:
cd "C:\Dept Structure"
for /D %%a in (*) do (
   set "dept=%%a"                         // For example: "165man"
   set "dept=!dept:~0,3!"                 // For example: "165"
   pushd %%a
   rem Process all folders here, ie: "Accident Investigation Report" "Address Change"
   for /D %%b in (*) do (
      rem Move all existent files from source folder to this folder
      move "C:\myLibrary\%%b\*!dept! %%b - *.*" "%%b" 2> NUL
   )
   popd
)
```

Comment: Ignore my last comment - I reran the code (albeit removing the 'example' comments) and it ran perfectly :) Thank you very much!